# How to make wall like Facebook?

Tags: html

I want to use (div) as a (textarea) element in html. Because when I used (textarea), it's width and height was not fixed. I want that when some one open my website they can write something on (div) like what peoples do in Facebook wall. In simple words I want to make wall like Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using HTML5, you can use the `contenteditable` attribute, e.g.

**HTML**

```
<div class="editor" contenteditable="true">
  bla bla bla
</div>
```

This would work how it is, but it should probably have a style, to look and behave nicer. For example:

**CSS**

```
div.editor {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid #303030;
}
```

This is what Facebook actually does.

`min-height` is how big it will start off. Then it will extend up to 100px high, then it will start using a scroll bar, because of `overflow-y: auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

You could <strike>nest the `textarea` inside a `div` with fixed size</strike> give your `textarea` a fixed size.

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 400px;">
    <textarea style="width:100%; height:100%;"></textarea>
</div>
```

```
<textarea style="width:200px; height:400px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: why not put dimensions directly on textarea ?

Answer (score -1):

With plain html you can only do a static representation of a wall. You'll need a server side language (e.g PHP) and some sort of storage for the wall comments such as files, database (e.g MySQL) etc